# Lost Dropbox tray icon on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dropbox

I've just updated my dropbox version by uninstalling the old (unsupported) version (but which has worked flawlessly for years) and installing version 1.6.2 from the dropbox site. Following the upgrade, the system tray icon is no longer visible. I've tried re-installing to no effect.
Dropbox does seem to be working but I could do with the tray icon back so that I can change my preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your suggestions. Just discovered this and it works

"I had this Problem and none of the above worked for me. However the solution was simple. Im using the gnome classic environment,hold Alt + WinKey whilst you right click on panel.select Add to panel and add NOTIFICATION AREA. Voilla Dropbox Icon appears Hope this can help someone "

Wonder how that got disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this will not be your favorite answer, but it is quite possible that the latest dropbox versions run their icons through gtk3+ instead of gtk2+ and are created for a gnome3 based environment instead of a gnome2. If memory serves, 12.04 is actually the last Ubuntu release built on top of gnome2 instead of gnome3.

However, all is not lost if your primary objective is to change your settings! Pop open your favorite terminal and run dropbox commands that way to change your preferences. If you need help figuring out how to use the "dropbox" command from CLI, simply run

```
dropbox help
```

or

```
man dropbox
```

The syntax for altering your settings is rather simple.

I hope this will be enough to get you by until you are able to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 or later.

MG